# Why is New Jersey (the US state) so associated with a kind of "low-brow worker guy" stereotype?

Tags: united-states

I don't live in NJ myself, nor have I ever been there.

I've heard numerous times, oftentimes from "New Jerseyians" themselves, jokes and sarcastic remarks relating to people (or males specifically, usually) from New Jersey being very "low-brow" or "uncultured", for example, they allegedly speak in a way which sounds "stupid" or "comical", and they allegedly don't care much about anything or anyone outside New Jersey. Of course, this doesn't apply to every single individual, but apparently to "a large percentage".

In this stereotype, it seems like the guy is oftentimes Italian-American. However, I have ***also*** heard a different stereotype about New Jersey where apparently an unusual amount of Jews live there, and in which this is the distinguishing "feature" of New Jersey. But I've also heard that about Long Island (which isn't a state but part of New York) and New York (the state, in general), so I don't know what to make of that.

I guess it's possible for both to be true.

What I'm wondering is why specifically New Jersey was "picked" for this (first) stereotype. That is, among the "Northern" states. I never hear anyone make fun of any other Northern US state in this way. There must be something I'm missing about the history of New Jersey.

I hope that my question is clear enough and doesn't offend anyone. Again, I'm trying to understand why this stereotype exists; I don't have any particular dislike/hate toward New Jersey or the people who live there.

Comment: Go back to the 30s/40s and it was Brooklyn. Perhaps some of it is that New Jersey is more or less a suburb of New York (City) and Philadelphia, so has little identity of its own?

Comment: It's not a universal US stereotype - mainly New York, I think. For example, I live in the state of Wisconsin, and we make fun of people from Illinois (called "flatlanders" or "FIBs"). To many Wisconsinites (especially those in the tourism industry), they're bad drivers, rude, demanding, and generally unpleasant people. Yet the livelihood of the people who say these things often depends on tourists from Illinois. People from Oklahoma pick on people from Missouri (which they pronounce "Misery"), pretty much everyone picks on West Virginia, and Texans look down on everyone not from Texas.

Comment: I can vouch that they make fun of New Jersey in the Philadelphia area as well. And heck, my Okie self has been known to make a crack or two about "New Jersey Cowboys" (particularly when Bon Jovi is playing)

Comment: I recall that is least two movies, The Addams Family (2019), and Ghostbusters (2016) , that they make fun of New Jersey. In the first, the family chooses NJ for being a dismal place where no one will find them. and in the second, when asked when where a contraption sends captured ghosts the answer is “probably NJ” or something like that.

Comment: Have you seen “on the waterfront”?  Brando films were very influential.

Comment: Some of it comes from [Saturday Night Live](https://www.nj.com/ledgerlive/2015/04/15_things_not_to_say_to_someone_from_new_jersey.html)